# How to get Infinity solution using Solve for $1/x ==0$?

Tags: equation-solving

Is there any way to output `Infinity` instead of an empty list?

```
Solve[1/x == 0, x]
(*{}*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One might try a projective geometry approach. It often works, but `Solve` emits a warning, so there's no guarantee.

```
expr = 1/x;
u/v /. Solve[expr == 0 /. x -> u/v, {u, v}]
(*  {ComplexInfinity}  *)

expr = (x - 1)/((x - 2) (x - 3));
u/v /. Solve[expr == 0 /. x -> u/v, {u, v}]
(*  {ComplexInfinity, 1}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting answer.

Comment: In general, could homogenize in a new variable `h`. Then setting `h->0` in solutions should give something plausible.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
Solve[1/x == \[Epsilon], {x}] /. \[Epsilon] -> 0
```

Out:

```
{{x -> ComplexInfinity}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your approach works for this example. However, I have a very big expression, where equating to a variable and getting solutions will itself take a very long time. I don't know why `Solve` doesn't return a trivial solution.

Comment: All right. Good luck.